# postgresql How to SELECT and UPDATE parent and child records from the same table?

Tags: postgresql

Hello I have the following records parents and children, you can tell by the **parent_load_record_id** column.

The thing is I need those records who have children and their children to have **false** in the **is_unique** field, since they are not unique anymore.

The parents who have no children have to stay as **is_unique = true**

| id | document_number | document_status | is_unique | parent_load_record_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 276983 | 49515 | INFORMED | true |  |
| 1060396 | 251013 | INFORMED | true |  |
| 177836 | 0000221 | INFORMED | true |  |
| 207775 | 0000221 | APPROVED | true | 177836 |
| 19342 | 0000221 | RESULTANT | true | 177836 |
| 19721 | 000456 | INFORMED | true |  |
| 19786 | 000456 | EDITED | true | 19721 |

The problem I'm having is. I'm trying to get all the parents with this query and I always get zero results (this query I use to check if my update actually worked)

```
SELECT 
l.id,
l.document_number,
l.document_status,
l.is_unique,
l.parent_load_record_id
FROM load_record l
WHERE l.parent_load_record_id IS NULL
AND l.id NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT lr.parent_load_record_id FROM load_record lr);
```

I use this query to update all children

```
UPDATE load_record SET is_unique = false WHERE parent_load_record_id IS NOT NULL
```

The problem comes when I have to UPDATE all parents with children

```
UPDATE load_record SET 
is_unique = false 
WHERE parent_load_record_id IS NULL 
AND id IN(SELECT DISTINCT lr.parent_load_record_id FROM load_record lr)
```

The Update is not really doing what it needs to do, just like the `SELECT` is there a reason for it? or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `SELECT DISTINCT lr.parent_load_record_id FROM load_record lr` returns a `NULL` row, which leads to `id NOT IN (…)` returning `NULL` as well ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/mxYsFQDR)). You can either filter them:

```
… AND l.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT lr.parent_load_record_id FROM load_record lr WHERE lr.parent_load_record_id IS NOT NULL);
```

<sup>([updated demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Az5WNfU7))</sup>

or just use a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
… AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM load_record lr
  WHERE lr.parent_load_record_id = l.id
)
```

<sup>([updated demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/eyOd_Ddu))</sup>

Comment: didn't realize that null values from that subquery will mess the query up, the update was good I can see. Thanx for the help

Comment: @ChrisG i learned the same thing today :-)